# Bing map JS API set up map center scale boundaries

Tags: javascript, bing-api

I have my root function that draws map tiles as follows, is there a way I could set up initial zoom based on window size, center map in certain position and limit map extents?

```
const renderMap = () => {
    window.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#map', {
            showDashboard: false,
            enableClickableLogo: false,
            showScalebar: false,
            showTermsLink: false,
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.grayscale
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const renderMap = () => {
    let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    let meterToPixRatio = 850000 / windowHeight;
    let scale = Math.floor(-1.4430 * Math.log(meterToPixRatio / 156434));
    let x = 
    let y = 
    let xextent = 
    let yextent = 
    window.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#map', {
            ...
            zoom: scale,
            center: centerLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(x, y),
            maxBounds: new Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect(centerLocation, xextent, yextent),
    });
}
```